# How to specify a default VPC for private hosted zone in a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

In order to create a private hosted zone I have [to associate it with one or more VPCs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html#w2ab2c21c10d879b9). I want to use a default VPC in the specific region. How can I specify it in the CloudFormation template without introducing the VPC id as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exactly do this

In the template you can say something like

```
"Parameters" : {
   myVpc:
    Description: "vpc id",
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>"
}
```

And the console will prepopulate the drop down with valid values

However the CLI can't do something like get the prepopulation and then pick the first one

I would guess to do this from a CLI first run soemthing like

```
   aws ec2 describe-vpcs --query 'Vpcs[*].[VpcId]'
```

Then edit the desired vpc (for instance the first on the list) into the CF template